# Scala case class recursion

Tags: scala, playframework, case-class

I am writing a recursive function

Can we use a case classs 'A' inside of the same case class 'A'

Ex:

```
case class FramesFolderData(key: String, title: String, parentId: Long, children: Option[List[FramesFolderData]])
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: It is working fine but I just got a  doubt that might be anything wrong in it or may be is it a  bad practice

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is valid Scala and is a good way to define a recursive data structure.

I would recommend removing the `Option` in the `children` field. You can indicate "no children" with an empty list (`Nil`) so there is probably no need to use an `Option` as well.

Comment: If the point of this is to convert it to/from JSON (I noticed the playframework tag and that's a pretty common use case with play), the Option is relevant otherwise any JSON read without that field would cause the JSON-to-case class conversion to fail. I could be wrong about the use case though. :)

Comment: @JamesWhiteley Good thought. I removed the playframework tag because I thought it wasn't relevant, but I have put it back in case you are right about the use case.

Comment: I am using it for play framework only. Thanks you  James and Tim  :)